# Filter and Store JSON values in NSArray

Tags: json

I'm getting a number of JSON values from a server, I want to Parse the JSON data's and filter them with respective to values of a single KEY.
The JSON Value is somewhat looks like

```
[{"id":8,"name":"General","visible":1,"summary":"","summaryformat":1,"modules":""},{"id":9,"name":"section01","visible":0,"summary":"","summaryformat":1,"modules":""}]
```

in the above like JSON value i want to split the values with respective to key "visible"

if visible = 0, i want to store them and if visible = 1, i should not store the value in array.

need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e] mutableCopy];

jsonArray = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject[@"visible"] intValue] == 1;
}];
```

I've blindly typed, so I don't know if this is syntactically correct

The point is that first you have to instantiate the `NSArray` through `NSJSONSerialization` class.
Then, you can filter it with a `NSPredicate` that just checks the `visible` property of the `NSDictionary` contained in the `NSArray`

You can probably do that also with a normal `NSPredicate` instead of a block, but I find blocks simpler :)

Comment: it shows the error as Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(__strong id, NSDictionary *__strong)' to parameter of type 'BOOL (^)(__strong id, NSDictionary *__strong)'

Comment: you're right, the block has to return a BOOL. Just add that to the code and it should work

Comment: how can we filter if it is an string value? (i.e) for "name" key.

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to filter by name, e.g. you only want names 'General', you can do return [evaluatedObject[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"General"];

Comment: or you can do return [evaluatedObject[@"name"] hasPrefix:@"G"]; 
If you only want names starting with 'G' etc.

Comment: the question is how can we filter if the name key is == general and != general1.