# filter Subdata's in JSON data in IOS

Tags: ios, json

I am new to iOS & JSON parsing I'm Getting some JSON data like,

```
 [
     {
         "id":3,
         "name":"SCORM 0",
         "visible":1,
         "summary":"",
         "summaryformat":1,
         "modules":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "url":"http:\/view.php?id=1",
                        "name":"Course01",
                        "visible":1,
                        "modicon":"http:\theme\/image.php\/standard\/scorm\/1378190687\/icon",
                        "modname":"scorm",
                        "modplural":"SCORM packages",
                        "indent":0
                    },
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "url":"http:\/\/192.168.4.196\/moodle\/mod\/forum\/view.php?id=2",
                        "name":"News forum",
                        "visible":1,
                        "modicon":"http:\//image.php\/standard\/forum\/1378190687\/icon",
                        "modname":"settle",
                        "modplural":"Forums",
                        "indent":0
                    }
                    ]
     },
     {
         "id":2,
         "url":"http:\/\/view.php?id=2",
         "name":"News forum",
         "visible":1,
         "modicon":"http:\/\theme\/image.php\/standard\/forum\/1378190687\/icon",
         "modname":"forum",
         "modplural":"Forums",
         "indent":0
     }
     ]
```

I need to separate the data's with respect to `"modname" != "forum"` and store the respective data's in the array.

Helps and Solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can take a look at a question from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639119/filter-and-store-json-values-in-nsarray/18639240?noredirect=1#comment27465379_18639240

Comment: @Vik the problem is i need to find a solution for != value in the keys and store all other values.

Comment: If you read the answer I gave in the question I linked, there is what you're looking for

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e] mutableCopy];

jsonArray = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ![evaluatedObject[@"modname"] isEqualToString:@"forum"];
}];
```

This is a sketch of what you could do

Comment: but this code didn't works the output contains  id = 2;
                indent = 0;
                modicon = "http:/87/icon";
                modname = forum;
                modplural = Forums;
                name = "News forum";
                url = "http:/view.php?id=2";
                visible = 1;

Comment: Have you put the ! after the return?

Comment: it shows the O/P like the following  {
                id = 2;
                indent = 0;
                modicon = "http:/php/standard/forum/1378190687/icon";
                modname = forum;
                modplural = Forums;
                name = "News forum";
                url = "http://forum/view.php?id=2";
                visible = 1;
            }
        );
        name = "SCORM 0";
        summary = "";
        summaryformat = 1;
        visible = 1;
    }

Comment: In the block, try to write:

BOOL checked = ![evaluatedObject[@"modname"] isEqualToString:@"forum"];
NSLog(@"Object %@ , checked = %@", evaluatedObject[@"modname"], checked ? @"YES" : @"NO");
return checked;

Comment: It showing Object (null) , checked = YES in the log and the same O/P for NSLog(@"Filtered %@",self.jsonData);

Comment: what's self.jsonData and how do you build it? If it's null, you're doing wrong something before

Comment: actually it's self.jsonArray

Comment: Ok, you're not helping me to help you. I don't know how this is going to have a happy ending if you don't collaborate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36939/discussion-between-prabhu-natarajan-and-vik)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.firstArray);

    NSArray * responseArr = json[@"Deviceinfo"];

    for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {
        [delegate.firstArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"id"]];
        [delegate.secondArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [delegate.thirdArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"visible"]];
        [delegate.fourthArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"summery"]];

    }
```

here all data arrange as per your key

Comment: How will this filter the array so "forum" modules are not included?

Comment: so add another key and get that value into new array like this    [delegate.fourthArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"forum"]];

Comment: The OP doesn't want separate arrays for each key, he wants all items excluding modname=="forum" in a single array. I'm also confused about the use of `delegate` in this answer.

Comment: i declare that array in APPDelegate.h that's why here i used to delegate.